# Silktest 13.5 All applications minimized on error

Tags: silktest

When Silktest (classic with open agent) is unable to find an object, it minimizes all applications and activates the desktop. 
Is it possible to override this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to override the feature of Silk Test moving mouse cursor to right most bottom. 
But the problem is due to aero peek view of Win7.
Disabling it from taskbar properties resolves the issue.